# Hibernate modelling a N:N Relationship

Tags: database-design, hibernate

Lets say that we have two entities
Entities:

- Bus        (idBus*)
- Stop       (idStop*,stopDescription)

Where a Bus passes from many Stops and vice versa, therefore the cardinality is **N:N**.

My question arises from the fact that when we consider to know the `idStop` and the `idBus` then we will also know a number of attributes like `Direction`,`NextStopID`, `TimeOfArrival`
How should i map those attributes?

My thought is to make a bridge table having `idStop` and `idBus` as Foreign Keys and a number of extra attributes that are not present in either the *Bus* or the *Stop* table, but I don't know if this is doable or the correct way to go.

Any thoughts?

Comment: [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9790225/939860)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a bridge table (also known as [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table), mapping table etc.) is a perfectly sensible solution in this case, and it is common for a bridge table to have other attributes beside the references to the tables being connected.

As a stationary object, a stop is just a place, which has coordinates and may also have a fixed name as well as some other properties. As a *part of a route*, though, it can be assigned the additional attributes you have mentioned that would depend on the route, i.e. on the specific bus number. Those would need to be stored in a different table, the one that would link the stop and the route.

So, if by "bus" you mean "bus number" (or "bus route", "bus line"), then by all means create a dedicated table with references to `Bus` and `Stop` and with whatever additional attributes you deem necessary. Note, though, that if `Bus` is meant to store information about specific buses (vehicles), then I would consider creating another entity (called `Route` perhaps) that I would link to in the bridge table. `Bus` would then probably reference that new entity, either directly or, again, through another bridge table (in case vehicles were allowed to work alternately on different lines).